# RequireJS: Uglification Not Working

Tags: gulp, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I must be making a mistake somewhere, but it's not being written to stdout during optimization.  I'm trying to optimize a file via requirejs, but the output isn't being minified.  According to the [documentation](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js), UglifyJS should minify the code.

At any rate, the following code is trivial, but it isolates the problem.

src/index.js:

```
require(['config'], function () {
    require(['myMod'], function (myMod) {
        console.log(myMod.x());
    })
})
```

src/myMod.js:

```
define(function () {
    let myMod = {
        x: 5
    };

    return myMod;
})
```

src/config.js:

```
define(function () {
    require.config({
        baseUrl: 'src'
    });
})
```

And here's the gulp task that is performing the optimization:

```
gulp.task('optimize', function (cb) {
    let config = {
        appDir: 'src',
        dir: 'dist/src',
        generateSourceMaps: true,
        preserveLicenseComments: false,
        removeCombined: true,
        baseUrl: './',
        modules: [{
            name: 'index',
            include: ['myMod']
        }]
    }

    let success = function (buildResponse) { console.log(buildResponse); cb() },
        error = function (err) { console.log(err); cb(err) }

    rjs.optimize(config, success, error)
})
```

After running the task, dist/src/index.js has all of the other modules included in it.  However, it's not minified, and none of the variables have been renamed.  Instead, it's as if the files were just concatenated, nothing more.  Could someone tell me (1) why is it not being minified?  (2) is UglifyJS throwing an error?  If so, is there a way to see it when the gulp task is being run?

**EDIT** Here's a link to RequireJS docs where it talks about using the optimizer in node, which is done in the gulp task mentioned above.  It's at the bottom under "Using the optimizer as a node module".

http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RequireJS' optimizer bundles UglifyJS2. UglifyJS2 does not handle ES6 or higher. If I take the options you use in your gulpfile, and plunk them into a separate file that I name `options.js`, and issue this command:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/r.js -o options.js
```

Then I get this output:

```
Tracing dependencies for: index
Uglify file: /tmp/t33/dist/src/index.js
Error: Cannot uglify file: /tmp/t33/dist/src/index.js. Skipping it. Error is:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (myMod)

If the source uses ES2015 or later syntax, please pass "optimize: 'none'" to r.js and use an ES2015+ compatible minifier after running r.js. The included UglifyJS only understands ES5 or earlier syntax.

index.js
----------------
config.js
index.js
myMod.js
```

As you can see, UglifyJS does fail to minify your file, and RequireJS just skips the minification step for that file. Since this is not an outright error, the file is still output, just not minified.

If you change `let` to `var` in `myMod.js`, then the issue disappears.

Unfortunately, since this is not an execution failure (`r.js` still runs, it just does not minify the file), the error is not signaled to the errback handler you pass to `rjs.optimize`. I don't see a way to catch such error in a Gulpfile. The safe thing to do is to set `optimize: "none"` and perform the minification as an additional build step after running `rjs.optimize`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm embarrassed to say this isn't the first time I've made this mistake:(  Hope it's the last, though!

Comment: correct, requirejs says we should minify ourself after rjs task. https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L116

Answer (score 0):

I had also run into the same issue where `require.js`'s optimizer (`r.js`) was combining different modules, but, it was not minify-ing the merged file. Although my run time environment is different from yours (using Java's Nashorn engine), this error was visible on my console :

```
If the source uses ES2015 or later syntax, please pass "optimize: 'none'" to r.js and use an ES2015+ compatible minifier after running r.js. The included UglifyJS only understands ES5 or earlier syntax.
```

Also, this error does not stop the optimizer from combining the files, it's just that the optimizer will not be able to mini-fy the merged file.

Comment: Please let me know how to fix this